# using flowtype to statically check mocha test code

Tags: javascript, mocha.js, flowtype

I have some complex Mocha code which I would like to statically check with FlowType because why not?

Below is a minimal repro:

```
/* @flow */

describe('it', function () {
    it('fails', function() {
        const s: number = 'flow spots this error';
    });
});
```

When I run Flow on this, Flow does indeed spot the problem with the assignment of `string` to `number` which shows that the approach is working to some extend.

However, I also get:

```
test/test.js:4
  4: describe('it', function () {
     ^^^^^^^^ identifier `describe`. Could not resolve name

test/test.js:5
  5:     it('fails', function() {
         ^^ identifier `it`. Could not resolve name
```

… apparently the Mocha test definitions run in an environment where these functions are globally available but looking at the test file there's nothing that would allow Flow to detect that.

I am not sure these problems are specific to Mocha but I don't feel I can confidently frame the question in broader terms, so my questions are:

1. how can I have Flow type check Mocha test code without suppressing every line that contains `describe` or `it` ?
2. is this is an instance of a broader class of situations and, if so, what would the latter be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Third-party libraries usually need definition files, i.e. files containing all the type information for a given library.

In this case, you need a definition file for mocha, which fortunately is provided by [flow-typed.](https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed)

Install it with

```
npm install -g flow-typed
```

then run

```
flow-typed install
```

It will automatically install all the available definition files for your dependencies, including mocha.

Comment: The flow-typed defs for mocha are currently a mostly useless autogenerated stub, and they don't fix the errors on `describe` and `it`.

Comment: @Andy you should change the imports to:
import {describe, it} from 'mocha';

Comment: @paulojean no, even so, try it out yourself.  If you `import {describe} from 'mocha'` and then write `describe('blah', 'blah', 'blah')`, you don't get any flow errors.  Though it's not a huge deal I guess.

Comment: This doesn't work for me. I get errors like `Cannot reference type it [1] from a value position.`

Answer (score 0):

You can simply declare the flow `describe`, `it` variables.

```
/* @flow */
declare var describe: any;
declare var it: any;

describe('it', function () {
    it('fails', function() {
        const s: number = 'flow spots this error';
    });
});
```

Comment: I don't think this solution is helpful. It would succeed I think in eliminating flowtype errors, but it won't add any meaninful type limitations to the functions in question since `any` is being used.

Comment: Yeah.. you can also remove flow-typed then, what's the point :D